# input file to Base64 failed on android devices

Tags: javascript, android, html, file-io

I am creating an application, where the user can select a picture from the local directory then I convert it to base64.
I wrote a javascript code that do this operation, and everything gonna fine on desktop browsers but it fail on android devices.

JS code:

```
function convert_input_image_base64(input, callback) {

        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var mime_type = input.files[0]["type"];
            if (mime_type === "image/png" || mime_type === "image/jpg" || mime_type === "image/jpeg") {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(e) {
                    alert(e.target.result);
                    callback(e.target.result);
                };
            }
            else {
                callback("INVALID_EXTENSION");
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
        else
            callback("ERROR");
    }
 $("#mobile_image_input").on("change", function() {
   convert_input_image_base64(this,function(response){
    alert(response);
   });
});
```